# Create variables named with the values of a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector like this:

```
sample_names<- c('Lung_22', 'Bladder_30', 'Colon_13')
```

I would like to create a loop which takes each sample name and create a new vector named as it:

My desired output would be:

```
Lung_22<-()

Bladder_30<-()

Colon_13<-()
```

Comment: [`?assign`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be better to create a named list where the list objects can be anything you want.

```
sample_names <- c("Lung_22", "Bladder_30", "Colon_13")

mylist = setNames(list(NULL, NULL, NULL), sample_names)
```

Then when you need to access the variables, you just have to refer to the list using `with`

```
with(mylist, Lung_22)
```

Comment: What happens if I have 50 elements in the vector instead of 3? I tried: 

```
mylist = setNames(list(replicate(50, NULL), sample_names)
```
What I would like is to add 50 NULL values

Answer (score 0):

We can use `list2env` to create multiple objects in the global env (though not recommended)

```
list2env(setNames(as.list(rep("", length(sample_names))), 
     sample_names), .GlobalEnv)
```